# how to create ruunable jar for hadoop using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

//I am getting exception while running hadoop jar file which convert pdf to //text and parse to mapper

```
    java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:549)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    17/06/08 19:12:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local815278758_0001 running in uber mode : false
    17/06/08 19:12:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    17/06/08 19:12:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local815278758_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
    17/06/08 19:12:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0



//Mapper class

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class WordCountMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Object, Object, Object> {
    private Text word = new Text();
    private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.progress();
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}


//Reducer class
package com.amal.pdf;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class WordCountReducer extends
        Reducer<Object, Object, Object, Object> {
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (LongWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();

        }
        context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
    }
}

//PDF record Reader class

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

public class PdfRecordReader extends RecordReader<Object, Object> {

    private String[] lines = null;
    private LongWritable key = null;
    private Text value = null;

    @Override

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();
        final Path file = split.getPath();

        /*
         * The below code contains the logic for opening the file and seek to
         * the start of the split. Here we are applying the Pdf Parsing logic
         */

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);

        FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());
        PDDocument pdf = null;
        String parsedText = null;
        PDFTextStripper stripper;
        pdf = PDDocument.load(fileIn);
        stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    //getting exception because of this line
        parsedText = stripper.getText(pdf);
        this.lines = parsedText.split("\n");    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        if (key == null) {

            key = new LongWritable();
            key.set(1);
            value = new Text();
            value.set(lines[0]);
        } else {

            int temp = (int) key.get();
            if (temp < (lines.length - 1)) {
                int count = (int) key.get();
                value = new Text();
                value.set(lines[count]);
                count = count + 1;
                key = new LongWritable(count);
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {

    }

}
```

//One more thing can anyone help to create runnable jar, configuration is not //showing inside eclipse because main is for hadoop environment.

Comment: Your title and error are totally different. Can you add your mapper and reducer code?

Comment: I have edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error on your console says:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

That means that the key-value pair you are providing to your mapper doesn't match it's definition.

Your mapper class should look something like this:

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private Text word = new Text();
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
             throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.progress();
            context.write(word, one);
         }
    }
}
```